# UberEats search api

Tags: uber-api

Does UberEats offer a search api? I've had a look at their [API page](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/introduction), however it mostly details about restaurant POS Api's. I ask this because I have seen [platforms](https://www.foodboss.com/) that have this functionality but as stated above, they offer no official Api for this. Is there a work around that I am missing? Or do platforms like these have private access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have private access most of the times. They create a software called [crawlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to get this piece of information

Comment: That's exactly what I thought! Do you think this is done on the go (per request)? Or do they store data for later use? I would have thought thousands of requests wouldn't go unnoticed.

Comment: I think they do both, normally you cache the data you request on a redis, with some regular base like every day so when a new user search for something you do the crawler to visite every site save the answer on a redis or other database cache this result and you are done.